# Upserting multiple entities to context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there a way to upsert multiple enitites to the Context Broker v2 in a single http-request like submitting an array in the request?

I have something like this in mind:

```
[POST] /v2/entities/?options=upsert

[
    {
        id: 'urn:ngsi-ld:xyz:123',
        type: 'xyz',
        ...
    },
    {
        id: 'urn:ngsi-ld:xyz:456',
        type: 'xyz',
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using `POST /v2/update` with `append` action type. For instance (example taken from  [NGSIv2 API walkthrough](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#batch-operations)):

```
POST /v2/op/update

{
  "actionType": "append",
  "entities": [
    {
      "type": "Room",
      "id": "Room3",
      "temperature": {
        "value": 21.2,
        "type": "Float"
      },
      "pressure": {
        "value": 722,
        "type": "Integer"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Room",
      "id": "Room4",
      "temperature": {
        "value": 31.8,
        "type": "Float"
      },
      "pressure": {
        "value": 712,
        "type": "Integer"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That will update `Room3` and `Room4` entities if they previously exist or create them if they don't previously exist.